# The function $\exp: \mathfrak{su}(2)\to SU(2)$ is surjective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups

**The function $\exp: \mathfrak{su}(2)\to SU(2)$ is surjective.**

I know that $SU(2)\cong\mathbb{S^3}$ and that $\mathbb{S^3}=\{x\in \mathbb{H}:|x|=1\}$ where $\mathbb{H}=\left \langle 1,i,j,k \right \rangle$, I also know that every element $A\in\mathfrak{su}(2) $ can be written as $A=\begin{bmatrix} bi& c+di\\ -c+di & -bi\end{bmatrix}$ where $b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$, but I don't know what the preimage of an arbitrary $B$ element in $SU(2)$ would be, could someone please help me with any ideas, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Any unitary matrix is normal, so it can be diagonalized by a unitary matrix.  Thus if $A \in SU(2)$, we can write 
$$ A = S \pmatrix{e^{i\theta} & 0\cr 0 & e^{-i\theta}} S^*$$
with $S \in U(2)$, and this is $\exp(B)$ where
$$ B = S \pmatrix{i\theta & 0\cr 0 &-i\theta} S^* \in {\frak su}(2)$$

Comment: Why does the diagonal matrix have the form $\begin{bmatrix} e^{i\theta}& 0\\ 0 & e^{-i\theta}\end{bmatrix}$ and not simply $\begin{bmatrix} a& 0\\ 0 & b\end{bmatrix}$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$? how did you conclude that the diagonal matrix had that shape?

Comment: @user402543 To be unitary, $a$ and $b$ must have norm $1$, so they are expressible as complex exponentials. Furthermore, the determinant of ${\rm diag}(a,b)$ is $ab$, but if it's in $SU(2)$ the determinant is $1$, so $ab=1$.